# ASP .NET anonymous users not getting stored in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, anonymous-users

I'm trying to setup anonymous users in MVC. For some reason it wont store the users in the database. I have added the following in the web.config

```
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />
```

It successfully creates the .ASPXANONYMOUS cookie when i visit the site but doesn't create the user in the database. Is this something i have to do manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be stored if you will try to save some data like for example something in this user's profile.

Comment: Hi @Tarkus I was wondering if you could share an example of how its possible to create an automatic anonymous creation on database using asp.net mvc - probably by creating in global.asax or other area - or any blog post will be appreciated. brgds!